# PropertyChangedEventHandler for static variable not changing

Tags: wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I wonder how to update my `UI` with my `static` property.
I have 2 properties in my model and one of them is `static`:

```
public class Machine : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;
    public string _name;
    public static int _counter;

    public void AddMachine(Machine machine)
    {
        _counter++;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChange("Name");
        }
    }

    public static int Counter
    {
        get { return _counter; }
        set
        {
            _counter = value;
            OnStaticlPropertyChanged("Counter");
        }
    }

    public virtual void NotifyPropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public static void OnStaticlPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = StaticPropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            StaticPropertyChanged(
                typeof(Machine),
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

As you can see i created another `PropertyChangedEventHandler` for my `static` value.
The other property (not the static one - Name) is working fine.
I am holding my object in collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<Machine> machines { get; set; }
```

And i can see the `Counter` is changing but not updating my `UI`, this is how i am trying to update my `UI` using `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock Name="tbStatusBar" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static my:Machine.Counter}}" />
```

So my question is what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You should probably replace `_counter++` by `Counter++` in AddMachine.

Comment: i already try it and this is not the problem

Comment: Are you actually using WPF 4.5? The StaticPropertyChanged event mechanism won't work with an older version.

Comment: I am working on .Net4

Comment: Update, i try to change my solution to .Net4.5 and this still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to make sure to use WPF 4.5, as the `StaticPropertyChanged` event mechanism won't work with an older version.

Then, in `AddMachine`, you should update the property, not its backing field:

```
public void AddMachine(Machine machine)
{
    Counter++;
}
```

Finally, you have to change the binding expression from a static source to a path to a static property (note the parenthesis):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(my:Machine.Counter)}" />
```

Comment: OK now this is working but i have another one, my static variable i accessing from different thread so every time i updated this field i do that this way: Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter); so now this not even compile with Counter instead of _counter so i change this into Counter++ and in the definition of this field i added volatile, is it OK now ?

Comment: Don't know. That's another question, I guess.

Comment: @Clemens How do we check the WPF version?